# My way for: only admin can register and all login system- but it's good? codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication, admin

Below I will show you a few of my classes:

Login_model, where I set session.

```
<?php
class Login_model extends CI_Model
{
     function __construct()
     {
          parent::__construct();
     }
    public $details;
    function validate_user( $login, $password ) 
    {
        $this->db->from('user');
        $this->db->where('login',$login );
        $this->db->where( 'password', $password);
        $login = $this->db->get()->result();  // = "select * from user where login = '" . $login . "' and password = '" . $password . "' "

        if ( is_array($login) && count($login) == 1 ) 
        {
            $this->details = $login[0];
            $this->set_session();
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    function set_session() 
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata( array(
                'user_id'=>$this->details->user_id,
                'login'=>$this->details->login,
                'isAdmin'=>$this->details->isAdmin,
                'isLoggedIn'=>true
            )
        );
    }

}
```

Login Controller where i fight with isLoggedIn. Did I won the fight? Is this good way?

```html
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller
{
     public function __construct()
     {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Login_model');
     }

    function index()
    {
        if( $this->session->userdata('isLoggedIn')) redirect('home');
        else redirect('login/check_user'); 
    }

    public function check_user()
    {
        if( $this->session->userdata('isLoggedIn')) redirect('home');

        //get the posted values
        $username = $this->input->post("txt_username");
        $password = $this->input->post("txt_password");

        //set validations
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("txt_username", "Username", "trim|required");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("txt_password", "Password", "trim|required");

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            //validation fails
            $this->load->view('login_view');
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }
        else
        {
            //validation succeeds
            if ($this->input->post('btn_login') == "Login")
            {
                //check if username and password is correct
                $usr_result = $this->Login_model->validate_user($username, $password);
                if ($usr_result) //active user record is present
                {
                    redirect("home");
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Invalid username and password!</div>');
                    redirect('login/check_user');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                redirect('login/check_user');
            }
        }
    }

    public function do_logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('login/check_user');
    }
}
```

home_view and here is question. Can I in this way check in view value isAdmin? I thinked also about new view for admin with button "signup" and check isAdmin in Controller, but then I have more views and views for admin is almost this same as for user, because difference is only button signup. The user registration is blocked that only the admin can go in there if someone typed in the browser corresponding url, he will not enter, but I have if in view. This is good? I'm just learning mvc model.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sesja gminy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
            <h1>Zalogowałeś się, oto Twoja strona startowa</h1>             
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2"> 
            <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right" style="margin-top:20px">
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('login/do_logout'); ?>"><button name="cancel" type="reset" class="btn btn-default"> Wyloguj się</button></a>
            </ul>        
        </div>
        <?php if( $this->session->userdata('isAdmin')==1 ) { ?>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 ">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right" style="margin-top:20px">
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('user'); ?>">Signup</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <ul>
        <?php foreach ($result as $item): ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <h4><b/>Sesja : <?php echo $item->description ?></b><br>
                Data sesji to: <?php echo $item->session_date ?></h4> 
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('Voting/'.$item->session_id.''); ?>"> <button type="submit" name class="btn btn-primary form-control">Wybierz</button> </a>
                <hr/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach;?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Home Controller, without Home_model, because there I only get data from database.

```html
<?php 
class Home extends CI_Controller
{

     public function __construct()
     {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Home_model');
        if( !$this->session->userdata('isLoggedIn') ) 
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Proszę się zalogować, aby móc przejśc na stronę startową!</div>');
            redirect('login/check_user');
        }
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['result']= $this->Home_model->get_all_session();
        $this->load->view('home_view', $data); 
        $this->load->view('footer'); 
    }    
}
```

To sum up, what is bad in my code?

In scale 1-10 is 7/10? :)
Thanks for your response and your precious time

Comment: i think you put your session value in data where you call your home_view  or show me your function wehre you call home_view

Comment: In the last code, in index I call view home_view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IN Controller**

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{

     public function __construct()
     {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Home_model');
        if( !$this->session->userdata('isLoggedIn') ) 
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Proszę się zalogować, aby móc przejśc na stronę startową!</div>');
            redirect('login/check_user');
        }
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['result']= $this->Home_model->get_all_session();
        $data['isAdmin']=$this->session->userdata('isAdmin');
        $this->load->view('home_view', $data); 
        $this->load->view('footer'); 
    }    
}
```

**IN View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sesja gminy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
            <h1>Zalogowałeś się, oto Twoja strona startowa</h1>             
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2"> 
            <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right" style="margin-top:20px">
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('login/do_logout'); ?>"><button name="cancel" type="reset" class="btn btn-default"> Wyloguj się</button></a>
            </ul>        
        </div>
        <?php if( $isAdmin==1 ) { ?>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 ">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right" style="margin-top:20px">
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('user'); ?>">Signup</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <ul>
        <?php foreach ($result as $item): ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <h4><b/>Sesja : <?php echo $item->description ?></b><br>
                Data sesji to: <?php echo $item->session_date ?></h4> 
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('Voting/'.$item->session_id.''); ?>"> <button type="submit" name class="btn btn-primary form-control">Wybierz</button> </a>
                <hr/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach;?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is more sexi :D